# How to capture the exit_code and stderr of the command that is run in C++?

Tags: c++, popen, stderr, exit-code

I'm writing a c++ program that executes and outputs (in real-time) a shell script, makefile or just another program. However I would like to have my program return differently when there are errors or no error.

```
#include "execxi.h"



using namespace std;


int execXI::run(string command)
{

    FILE *in;
    char buff[512];
    // is this the check for command execution exited with not 0?
    if(!(in = popen(command.c_str(), "r"))){
            // I want to return the exit code and error message too if any
        return 1;
    }
    // this part echoes the output of the command that's executed
    while(fgets(buff, sizeof(buff), in)!=NULL){
        cout << buff;
    }
    pclose(in);
    return 0;



}
```

is what I have so far.

Let's say this script ran `make` to build a program and it gave an error like so

```
on_target_webkit_version out/Release/obj/gen/webkit_version.h
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "../build/webkit_version.py", line 107, in <module>
    sys.exit(main())
  File "../build/webkit_version.py", line 103, in main
    return EmitVersionHeader(*sys.argv[1:])
  File "../build/webkit_version.py", line 86, in EmitVersionHeader
    webkit_revision = GetWebKitRevision(webkit_dir, version_file)
  File "../build/webkit_version.py", line 60, in GetWebKitRevision
    version_info = lastchange.FetchVersionInfo(
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'FetchVersionInfo'
make: *** [out/Release/obj/gen/webkit_version.h] Error 1
```

- Is it possible for me to know that this exited with error?

  - Does that exit with code `else than 0` since it is an error?
  - Is that last part outputted in `stderr`?

Considering that `make` exited with code not `0`, let's say `1`, and it output in `stderr` is it not possible for me to capture these exit codes and error message in the end?

How can I capture the exit code and `stderr` after outputting the results of the program, and return the `exit code`/ `stderr` in the function?

Comment: pclose returns an exit status.

Comment: http://jineshkj.wordpress.com/2006/12/22/how-to-capture-stdin-stdout-and-stderr-of-child-program/

Answer (score 23, accepted):

If you are interested in the error code, this is a more portable way of getting it rather than dividing by 256:

```
printf("Exit code: %i\n", WEXITSTATUS(pclose(fp)));
```

However, `popen` is one way, so you are either creating further workarounds by the usual redirection style in shell, or you follow this untested code to do it right:

```
#include <unistd.h>
#include <stdio.h>

/* since pipes are unidirectional, we need two pipes.
   one for data to flow from parent's stdout to child's
   stdin and the other for child's stdout to flow to
   parent's stdin */

#define NUM_PIPES          2

#define PARENT_WRITE_PIPE  0
#define PARENT_READ_PIPE   1

int pipes[NUM_PIPES][2];

/* always in a pipe[], pipe[0] is for read and 
   pipe[1] is for write */
#define READ_FD  0
#define WRITE_FD 1

#define PARENT_READ_FD  ( pipes[PARENT_READ_PIPE][READ_FD]   )
#define PARENT_WRITE_FD ( pipes[PARENT_WRITE_PIPE][WRITE_FD] )

#define CHILD_READ_FD   ( pipes[PARENT_WRITE_PIPE][READ_FD]  )
#define CHILD_WRITE_FD  ( pipes[PARENT_READ_PIPE][WRITE_FD]  )

void
main()
{
    int outfd[2];
    int infd[2];

    // pipes for parent to write and read
    pipe(pipes[PARENT_READ_PIPE]);
    pipe(pipes[PARENT_WRITE_PIPE]);

    if(!fork()) {
        char *argv[]={ "/usr/bin/bc", "-q", 0};

        dup2(CHILD_READ_FD, STDIN_FILENO);
        dup2(CHILD_WRITE_FD, STDOUT_FILENO);

        /* Close fds not required by child. Also, we don't
           want the exec'ed program to know these existed */
        close(CHILD_READ_FD);
        close(CHILD_WRITE_FD);
        close(PARENT_READ_FD);
        close(PARENT_WRITE_FD);

        execv(argv[0], argv);
    } else {
        char buffer[100];
        int count;

        /* close fds not required by parent */       
        close(CHILD_READ_FD);
        close(CHILD_WRITE_FD);

        // Write to child’s stdin
        write(PARENT_WRITE_FD, "2^32\n", 5);

        // Read from child’s stdout
        count = read(PARENT_READ_FD, buffer, sizeof(buffer)-1);
        if (count >= 0) {
            buffer[count] = 0;
            printf("%s", buffer);
        } else {
            printf("IO Error\n");
        }
    }
}
```

The code is from here:

http://jineshkj.wordpress.com/2006/12/22/how-to-capture-stdin-stdout-and-stderr-of-child-program/

Comment: For me, using `WEXITSTATUS` with `pclose()` is returning `1` for successful and `-1` for unsuccessful.  Does this sound right, or have I done something wrong?

Comment: there's an explanation https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/utah-c/g4MpZVnJ7es regarding different non-0 exit codes

Comment: Use `WEXITSTATUS` only if `WIFEXITED` returns true. This is for cases where a program didn't terminate normally.
`int st = pclose(fp); if(WIFEXITED(st)) printf("Exit code: %i\n", WEXITSTATUS(st));`

Answer (score 11):

> The returnvalue of the child process is in the top <strike>16</strike> 8 bits. You have
>   to divide the returned value of pclose by 256, then you get the
>   searched return value of the child process.

Gotten from http://bytes.com/topic/c/answers/131694-pclose-returning-termination-status-command

My answer would be `pclose(in)/256` is exit code.

I still don't know how to capture stderr or sdtout differently but until there's an answer for that I will accept this as my answer.

Comment: Same problem here. Did you find a solution to your open question? My workaround would be piping the stderr into a file and to read that again with a popen call.

Comment: @Strubbl Kind of... check this out https://github.com/aponxi/npm-execxi/blob/master/execxi.cpp I've written a C++ extension for nodejs to execute shell commands. I think I haven't implemented dividing stderr and stdout because not all programs used stderr for errors is what I figured. And I believe I came up with something to prevent `file write than read` kind of approach. I hope reading what I did in that code helps (it's been a while so I'm fuzzy on the details.)

Comment: You could also use shell redirection, 2>&1, and search for error messages.

Comment: @Logan: I submitted an answer based on my knowledge and the comment above.

Comment: It's better to use `WEXITSTATUS(pclose(xxx))` than divide by 256. Also, if dividing by 256 gets the right answer, then the exit code is in the top 8 bits, not the top 16 bits as the answer originally stated.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks for the reply about exit code Logan.

I believe a round-trip to get stderr would be to redirect it to a temporary file:

```
FILE* f = popen("cmd 2>/tmp/tmpfile.txt", "r");
```

Comment: Create a unique output file (perhaps using pid), so that when you need to run 2+ copies, you get useful output.

Comment: Use `tempnam`, `tmpfile` or `tmpnam` to create temporarty files, **never** hardcode the names.

Comment: I believe redirecting stederr to stdout works with popen: popen("command 2>&1", "r");

Answer (score 0):

This question is quite old, but I still cannot find anywhere a really complete and elegant solution to the problem which is treated here - executing OS command and catching all stdout, stderr and exit status.
So I propose the below example, which is not using popen(), but forks a process and attempts to intercept all information. There is also a stdin pipe for more interactive usage, but not used in the below example.
Coding in C.

```
#include <unistd.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <errno.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <sys/epoll.h>
#include <sys/wait.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

/* These definitions are for issuing error messages.
 */
#define WarningMessage( ErrMess) fprintf(stderr, "%s() (file %s, line %d): Warning: %s\n", \
    __func__, __FILE__, __LINE__, (ErrMess) )
#define ErrorMessage( ErrMess) fprintf(stderr, "%s() (file %s, line %d): Error: %s\n", \
    __func__, __FILE__, __LINE__, (ErrMess) )
#define ErrorMessageFromCall(Func) fprintf(stderr, "%s() (file %s, line %d): Error from function %s(): Errno: (%d) [%s]\n", \
    __func__, __FILE__, __LINE__, (Func), errno, strerror(errno))
#define ErrorMessageFromCall1(Func) fprintf(stderr, "%s() (file %s, line %d): Error from function %s()\n", \
    __func__, __FILE__, __LINE__, (Func))

#define buffLen 1024
#define MAX_EVENTS 10


int main()
{
  int pip0[2], pip1[2], pip2[2];
  int FDChildStdin, FDChildStdout, FDChildStderr;
  int iret, i;
  pid_t PID, PID1;
/* This is the command to execute and its arguments. See execve() for more details */  
  char Command[]="/usr/bin/ls";
  char *argv[3]={ [0]="ls", "-l", };
  char *envp[1]={};
  
  char buff[buffLen];
  int FDEpollInst;
  struct epoll_event ev, events[MAX_EVENTS];
  int nfds;

  iret= pipe( pip0);
  if( iret)
  {
    ErrorMessageFromCall( "pipe()");
    return -1;
  }
  iret= pipe( pip1);
  if( iret)
  {
    ErrorMessageFromCall( "pipe()");
    return -1;
  }
  iret= pipe( pip2);
  if( iret)
  {
    ErrorMessageFromCall( "pipe()");
    return -1;
  }

  PID= fork();
  if( PID < 0)
  {
    ErrorMessageFromCall("fork()");
    return -2;
  }
  if( PID == 0)
  {
/* here we are in the child process  
   This child process will be reading from pip0, writing to pip2 and pip3. 
   * This will be the new stdin, stdout and stderr.
   * The process should not know about the previous file descriptors. */     
    close( pip0[1]);
    close( pip1[0]);
    close( pip2[0]);
    
    iret= dup2(pip2[1], 2);
    if( iret == -1)
    { /* This will be probably the last message written to the original stderr from this process... */
        ErrorMessageFromCall( "In child process: pipe()");
        return -1;
    }
    iret= dup2(pip1[1], 1);
    if( iret == -1)
    { /* This will already go to the stderr pipe. See the previous call. */
        ErrorMessageFromCall( "pipe()");
        return -1;
    }
    iret= dup2(pip0[0], 0);
    if( iret == -1)
    { 
        ErrorMessageFromCall( "pipe()");
        return -1;
    }
    close( pip0[0]);
    close( pip1[1]);
    close( pip2[1]);

    iret= execve(Command, argv, envp);
    if( iret == -1)
    { 
        ErrorMessageFromCall( "execve()");
        return -1;
    } 
/* Now, the Command runs in this process. No more control in this code. */
    
  } else
  {
/* here we are in the parent process  */
/* The child process will be writing to pip0, reading from pip2 and pip3.
 * This process will use the oposite ends of the pipes. */     
    FDChildStdin= pip0[1];
    FDChildStdout= pip1[0];
    FDChildStderr= pip2[0];

   FDEpollInst= epoll_create1(0);
   if (FDEpollInst == -1) 
   {
       ErrorMessageFromCall( "epoll_create1()");
       return -2;
   }

   ev.events = EPOLLIN;
   ev.data.fd = FDChildStdout;
   if(epoll_ctl(FDEpollInst, EPOLL_CTL_ADD, FDChildStdout, &ev) == -1) 
   {
       ErrorMessageFromCall( "epoll_ctl()");
       return -2;
   }
   ev.events = EPOLLIN;
   ev.data.fd = FDChildStderr;
   if(epoll_ctl(FDEpollInst, EPOLL_CTL_ADD, FDChildStderr, &ev) == -1) 
   {
       ErrorMessageFromCall( "epoll_ctl()");
       return -2;
   }

   for( ;; )
   {
/* Wait for data from child. Timeout 10 seconds. 
 * Would be better to decrease timeout in subsequent calls,
 * if loop is repeated because of interrupt (errno == EINTR). */
       nfds = epoll_wait(FDEpollInst, events, MAX_EVENTS, 10000);
       if( (nfds == -1) && (errno != EINTR))
       {
           ErrorMessageFromCall("epoll_wait()");
           return -2;   
       } 
       if( nfds > -1) break;
   }
   if( nfds == 0)
   {
       printf( "No data from child available within the timeout.\n");
   }
   for( i= 0; i< nfds; i++)
   {
     if( events[i].events & EPOLLIN) printf( "file is available for read(2) operations.\n");
     if( events[i].events & EPOLLOUT) printf( "file is available for write(2) operations.\n");
     if( events[i].events & EPOLLRDHUP) printf( "Stream socket peer closed connection, or shut down writing half of connection.\n");
     if( events[i].events & EPOLLPRI) printf( "exceptional condition on the file descriptor.\n");
     if( events[i].events & EPOLLERR) printf( "Error condition happened on the associated file descriptor\n");
     if( events[i].events & EPOLLHUP) printf( "Hang up happened on the associated file descriptor.\n");

       if( events[i].data.fd == FDChildStdout)
       {
           printf("Event in stdout of child.\n"  );
           iret= read(FDChildStdout, buff, buffLen);
/* Do not be tempted to read again, when not all data have been read at once.
 * This is a blocking fd! It is necessary to check for presence of data before another
 * attempt of read. Else it may hang forever. 
 * Same below for stderr. */           
           fprintf( stdout, "stdout from child: ");
           write( 1, buff, iret);
       } else if( events[i].data.fd == FDChildStderr)
       {
           printf("Event in stderr of child.\n"  );
           iret= read(FDChildStderr, buff, buffLen);
           fprintf( stdout, "stderr from child: ");
           write( 1, buff, iret);
       } else 
       {
           printf("Event in unknown fd!\n"  );
       }
   }
/* Wait for child to catch return code. */
    PID1= wait(&iret);
    if (PID1 < 0)
        printf("Failed to wait for process %d (errno = %d)\n", (int)PID, errno);
    else if (PID1 != PID)
        printf("Got return status of process %d (status 0x%.4X) when expecting PID %d\n",
               PID1, iret, (int)PID);
    else if (WIFEXITED(iret))
        printf("Process %d exited with normal status 0x%.4X (status %d = 0x%.2X)\n",
               PID1, iret, WEXITSTATUS(iret), WEXITSTATUS(iret));
    else if (WIFSIGNALED(iret))
        printf("Process %d exited because of a signal 0x%.4X (signal %d = 0x%.2X)\n",
               PID1, iret, WTERMSIG(iret), WTERMSIG(iret));
    else
        printf("Process %d exited with status 0x%.4X which is %s\n",
               PID1, iret, "neither a normal exit nor the result of a signal");
}
  return 0;
}
```