# Run linux command and get exit code in Delphi

Tags: linux, delphi

I would like to know if it's possible to run a command and get its exit code. I have seen that it's possible to capture the `stdout` of the process, but I have not found anything about the exit code. Is it possible to do this on **Linux**?

**Delphi version**: 10.4

**OS**: Ubuntu 18.04

This is the unit I use to run the command and get its output:

```
unit TestRunCommand;

interface

uses
  System.SysUtils,
  Posix.Base,
  Posix.Fcntl;

type
  TStreamHandle = pointer;

function popen(const command: MarshaledAString; const _type: MarshaledAString): TStreamHandle; cdecl; external libc name _PU + 'popen';
function pclose(filehandle: TStreamHandle): int32; cdecl; external libc name _PU + 'pclose';
function fgets(buffer: pointer; size: int32; Stream: TStreamHandle): pointer; cdecl; external libc name _PU + 'fgets';
function RunCommand(const acommand: MarshaledAString): String; forward;

implementation

function RunCommand(const acommand: MarshaledAString): String;

// run a linux shell command and return output
var
  handle: TStreamHandle;
  data: array [0 .. 511] of uint8;

  function bufferToString(buffer: pointer; maxSize: uint32): string;

  var
    cursor: ^uint8;
    endOfBuffer: nativeuint;
  begin
    if not assigned(buffer) then
      exit;
    cursor := buffer;
    endOfBuffer := nativeuint(cursor) + maxSize;
    while (nativeuint(cursor) < endOfBuffer) and (cursor^ <> 0) do
    begin
      result := result + chr(cursor^);
      cursor := pointer(succ(nativeuint(cursor)));
    end;
  end;

begin
  result := '';
  handle := popen(acommand, 'r');
  try
    while fgets(@data[0], sizeof(data), handle) <> nil do
    begin
      result := bufferToString(@data[0], sizeof(data));
    end;
  finally
    pclose(handle);
  end;
end;

end.
```

Comment: `pclose(handle);` returns a value that if the process exited normally the top 8 bits are the exit code. So quick and dirty: `ExitCode := pclose(handle) div 256;`   See: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15058876